# Can zone plug a new monitor in via VGA without installing drivers?

Tags: display, vga, analog

This is probably an incredibly stupid question, but if I plug a new monitor into a computer via VGA are any drivers for the monitor required? Or, will it just display?

Comment: It will display, but if the monitor is not recognised by your OS, it will likely display in a default, safe mode, such as VGA. An installation disc for the monitor won't add any drivers, but it will define all the operating modes, allowing you to choose the resolution you want.

Answer (score 0):

The graphics card you plug the monitor into needs drivers. The monitor itself does not.